# Unresolved reference MagicMock

Tags: python, python-3.x, magicmock

I want to Mock a method in a Python Test. 
In order to do this I need MagicMock which I try to import it like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
```

Even after I clicked several times on install in PyCharm and although I see magicmock 0.0.3 under Preferences/Project Interpreter, I get this error:

```
 from unittest.mock import MagicMock
 ImportError: No module named mock
```

The import statement I saw [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). **What do I wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Py3.5` (basically versions `>= 3.3`) [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) has been incorporated in the Standard Library as you linked in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). So, the statement:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
```

should **never** raise `ImportErrors`.

---

I'm guessing you're either using a `Py3` version `< 3.3` or are using `Py2.7`.

In these cases you should `pip install mock` first and then import:

```
from mock import MagicMock
```